# rails get all namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have namespaced models such as

```
modes/ticket/box_office.rb
modes/ticket/current.rb
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.descendants` will give all the descendants of `ActiveRecord::Base`

Is there a way to find only namespaced models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return an array with the class names (ie. strings):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map(&:to_s).select {|x| x.match('::')}
```

while this will return the actual class objects:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.select {|x| x.name.match('::')}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that all the models have to be already loaded for this to work. Often enough, this is not the case... (rake tasks, initializers, monkey patches).

Comment: Unfortunately no better way to do it. But yes this does work.